# How do I turn on animation timeline options in Photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, animation

My version of Adobe Photoshop CS6 (standard) doesn't have the options on the animation timeline that appear to be available on all the Photoshop Animation tutorials. Onion skinning, different layers etc all not available.

The option in Photoshop menu > Layers to have a new video layer isn't there at all. I am on the correct operating system, OSX 10.7 and have checked my Photoshop preferences.

I have read online that other people have had the same problem but there doesn't seem to be any resolution. Has anyone found a way of turning on these other options and is it even possible?

It appears from other sites that having the extended version is not necessary.

Many thanks

Comment: I think you answered your own question by adding "(standard)" to your post. "Extended" has the video features.

Answer (score 4):

You need Photoshop Extended version (or a subscription to Creative Cloud's Photoshop) to get the animation timeline and additional features (stacks, 3D tools, etc.).

So basically it's not possible with your current version of Photoshop. See http://prodesigntools.com/whats-the-difference-photoshop-cs6-vs-photoshop-cs6-extended.html for more details about the differences bewteen the Photoshop versions.